# Is it okay to ask whether my understanding about something is correct?

Tags: discussion, scope, confirmation

I am new to the stack overflow forums.   I have been dealing with a question which was answered in stackoverflow about a year ago.  My question is directly related to the topic in this thread:

[variable scope in statement blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693138/variable-scope-in-statement-blocks)

by the responses in the thread, it seems that some of the readers "accepted" the answer but did not really understand the theory on which it is based.

I would like to know if it is "proper" for me to ask what is basically the same question, while providing the answer as I understand it with the goal of having someone confirm that my understanding is correct.

Comment: No.  Post your answer to the same question if you really have to.